# How to create threads in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have got easy Perl script where I have got a BIG loop and inside this I invoke more or less million times function `my_fun()`. I would like to create pool of threads which will be dealing with it - max 5 threads in this same time will be invoking this method in loop.

It is really important for me to use the fastest library - It will be really nice to see examples.

My code looks like this:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 1000000 ; $i++) {
        my_fun();
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: To you really need **threads** (as in, shared memory, concurrency control) or merely independent parallelized execution? If the latter, consider Parallel::ForkManager - the POD has example of how to do 5 forks at a time easily.

Comment: @DVK I didn't see your comment. Didn't want to steal your idea, sorry.

Comment: @simbabque - no problem whatsoever. (1) I was too lazy to look up details and post anyway; (2) Content on SO is CC, I don't own it :) ; (3) Not like I never borrowed a comment idea for an answer, though like you I always explicitly tell the commenter. Anyway, +1 for a good example code

Comment: If you want the fastest way to do your thing, why do you restrict which ways can be used (by saying it has to use a pool of threads), and why didn't you tell us what that thing is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/module/Parallel::ForkManager). It's using `fork`, not threads, but it should get your job done very simply.

Example lifted from the docs and slightly altered:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(5); # number of parallel processes

for my $i (0 .. 999999) {
  # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
  my $pid = $pm->start and next;

  #... do some work with $data in the child process ...
  my_fun();

  $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: any solution for Windows like this ?

Comment: @javaGirl it should work on Windows. I just tested it on Windows and it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

We can't give you the fastest way, since that depends on the work, and you didn't tell us what the work is.

But you did ask about threads, so I'll give you the foundation of a threaded application. Here is a worker model. It's robust, maintainable and extendable.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue qw( );   # Version 3.01+ required

my $NUM_WORKERS = 5;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   ...
}

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
my @workers;
for (1..$NUM_WORKERS) {
   push @workers, async {
      while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
         worker($job);
      }
   };
}

$q->enqueue($_) for @jobs;        # Send work
$q->end();                        # Tell workers they're done.
$_->join() for @workers;          # Wait for the workers to finish.
```

This is a basic flow (one-directional), but it's easy to make bi-directional by adding a response queue.

This uses actual threads, but you can switch to using processes by switching `use threads;` to `use forks;`.

[Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager) can also be used to provide a worker model, but it's continually creating new processes instead of reusing them. This does allow it to handle child death easily, though.

Ref: [Thread::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue) (or [Thread::Queue::Any](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Thread::Queue::Any))

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) documentation.

Comment: yes, of course I have already read it but I need the fastest way, so why I asked