# How can I create a thread without it running right away?

Tags: multithreading, perl

Consider the following code:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $threadCount; $i++) {

    if($isResumed) {

        # TODO: load stats from DB      
    }
    else {

        $stats->{workers}->{$i}        = &share({});            
        $stats->{workers}->{$i}->{tid} = undef; 
        $stats->{workers}->{$i}->{foo} = "bar";
        $stats->{workers}->{$i}->{abc} = 123;                               
    }

    # create the worker thread
    my $thr = threads->create(\&worker);    
    # TODO: find a way to store the TID in the $i slot. why have two differetn IDs? 
    $stats->{workers}->{$i}->{tid} = $thr->tid();
}
```

I am using the $stats hash to hold data that should be shared between threads, as well as data about what each thread is doing. The problem I have is that I would like to reference the thread data in this hash based on the TID, not an arbitrary value assigned by $i in the loop.

When I create the thread, the work starts immediately, but it cannot start its work until the hash values are set. So, if I do:

```
$thr = threads->create(\&worker);
$stats->{workers}->{$thr->tid()} = &share({});
```

It will not work because not all the data it needs is set yet.

So basically, is there a way for me to create a thread, but defer it from running its code until I specifically tell it to? Something like:

```
$thr = threads->create(\&worker);
$stats->{workers}->{$thr->tid()} = &share({});
$thr->start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, after reviewing my code; I realized that I was over complicating it, and did not truly need to know the TIDs.

I ended up just passing the relevant data to the worker subroutine during the create statement.

That being said though, People who come across this question should take a look at Jean's answer, as it appears to be a promising solution to my original problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is highly recommended to use [Thread::Queue](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html) for stuff like this

Comment: I just looked at the documentation for it, but I am still unsure how I would apply it here.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370935/how-to-create-threads-in-perl/12374670#12374670) example.

Comment: @ikegami This is a nice code snippet, but I am a little confused at that it is doing exactly. Could you go into a little detail? I think this may be exactly what I need, but I am hesitant to use it without understanding it a bit more first.

Comment: The idea is to create a bunch of workers, and assign them work through a queue. The workers will block until work is available. When work becomes available, one of the workers will unblock and start the job. If work comes in when all the workers are busy, it will remain in the queue until a worker grabs it.

Comment: I'm understanding it a bit more, but I tinhk I am confused about these two lines: "while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {" and "$q->enqueue($_) for @jobs;".